# Обработка нажатий мыши с помощью команд MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

Хочу повесить обработчик `MouseRightButtonDown` на окно с помощью команды. 
Желаемый результат: `MouseRightButtonDown="{Binding команда}";` Можно ли это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Легко. Используйте `InvokeCommandAction` из `Windows.Interactivity`.

```
<Window x:Class="..."
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        ...>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseRightButtonDown">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding команда}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Window>
```

Не забудьте добавить ссылку на сборку `System.Windows.Interactivity`

Comment: не понимаю почему, но не работает. Программа запускается, но при нажатии на правую кнопку команда не отрабатывает. Хотя эта же команда висит на некоторых контролах и работает все хорошо.

Comment: @Lightness: Может быть, до окна команда просто не доходит? Что будет, если положить обработчик события в code behind для проверки?

Comment: в code behind работает

Comment: @Lightness: Хорошо, а может, опечатка в названии команды или там `DataContext` не установлен?

Comment: Спасибо, проблему нашел. DataContext был подключен до подключения ресурсов. Поменял местами и все стало хорошо.

Comment: @Lightness: Если вы следуете паттерну MVVM, окно вообще не должно устанавливать самому себе `DataContext`. Это задача внешнего кода.

Comment: @Lightness: Пожалуйста!